# How to find out a date a follower started following a certain channel on twitch?

Tags: web-services, twitch

Is there a way to find out the date someone started following a channel on twitch?

I was looking at Twitch's web api. But I couldn't figure it out. Anyone knows? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it here
https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/follows.md#example-request-2

`created_at` is what you need

Example request is

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' \
-X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1/follows/channels/test_channel
```